# Header-variables in bounced emails: what points could have an effect if they are deleted or not?

Tags: c#, email, email-bounces

We use BounceStudio in order to analyze the bounced emails for a newsletter-system. The headers are added like this:

```
// Namespace System.Net.Mail
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Headers.Add("X-BPS1", UserId);
// etc.
smptClient.Send(mail);
```

So far so good. The interesting thing is that a lot of the bounced emails don't include the headers we added. I couldn't figure out on what that could depend if the headers are preserved or not? One interesting observation I made is the fact that it seems to depend on which from-address is used (they are sent with the same smtp though). From newsletter A with from-address A I receive most header variables (about 90%, which is good I guess), from newsletter B with from-address B (and other receivers of course) I only receive about 20% of the header variables, the other 80% of the bounced mails don't include the header-information. All mails are html-mails and technically the same.

Leaves the question what could influence the headers within the bounced mails? Does somebody know details or good sources about that subject?
Or how could I design the system better?

Am I right that the best way might still be hiding the information within the from- or return-path email-adress and then parse it out from there? But this would include configuring the smtp with wildcards or similar, don't have much knowledge there.

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote MTA generates the bounce, you are at its mercy. Unsurprisingly, Windows MTAs seem to be particularly tacky in this regard. The standard solution is VERP, i.e. a unique envelope sender address (and hence Return-Path:) for each recipient.